# Does python have this way of writing it?

Tags: python

Recently，I have some trouble in writing python, I wonder whether this sentencce `logger.handlers = [console_handler]bash src/persona_preprocess.sh` ,it's right side is legal in python?

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
def init_logger(log_file=None, log_file_level=logging.NOTSET):
    log_format = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s] %(message)s")
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.handlers = [console_handler]bash src/persona_preprocess.sh
```

the code is like this. I want to know how can I change the last line to make it valid,thank you

Comment: No, that doesn't look like valid python. however, if you provide a little more syntax, we might be able to help you find a valid statement that does what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

That line looks like someone accidentally tried to run a script (`bash src/persona_preprocess.sh`) in their terminal while typing focus was still in the editor window (so instead of running anything, they added garbage to the Python code). Delete the `bash src/persona_preprocess.sh` and it's valid Python code.